# Akuzativo kaj "en"

Tags: accusative

Mi lastatempe trovis en Esperanta libro la jenan frazon: "Ni enterigis la kvin [kadavrojn] en unu tombon". Kial la '-n' finaĵo en "tombon"? La objekto de la verbo "enterigis" estas "la kvin kadavrojn". La tombo estas kie la kvin estis enterigitaj. La uzado de '-n' por direkto ankaŭ ne ŝajnas taŭga ("enterigi" = ni metis la kadavrojn en la tombo, kovris ilin per tero, ktp, ne simple movis ilin al ĝi). Tamen, mi supozas ke por enterigi ilin en la tombo oni devas komence movi ilin al ĝi...

Do: Kial '-n' estas uzata, kaj kiam oni devas fari tion en similaj situacioj? Ĉu en ĉi tia frazo oni ĉiam devas fari ĝin, aŭ simple "en tombo" ankaŭ estas akceptebla?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oni uzas *-n* kun lokaj prepozicioj por signifi **direkton**. Sen *-n* la frazo dirus "estante en unu tombo, ni enterigis ...", kio, kvankam gramatike ĝusta, havas alian signifon. Pli informoj estas troveblaj en PMEG [ĉi tie](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/n/direkto.html#i-sgp).

Mi aparte ŝatas ĉi tiun ekzemplon:

> - La birdo flugas en la **ĉambro** (= ĝi estas en la ĉambro kaj flugas en ĝi)
> - La birdo flugas en la **ĉambron** (= ĝi estas ekster la ĉambro kaj flugas nun en ĝin)

Answer (score 6):

Eble ĉi tiu demando baziĝas sur miskompreno de la vorto *tombo*. Se vi imagas tombon kiel grandetan ĉambron sub la tero kiun oni povas eniri por enterigi kadavrojn, via demando havas sencon, ĉar la vivantoj homoj jam estus en la «tombo» dum ili enterigas la kadavrojn, kaj la akuzativo ne estus tiel sencohava. Tio estus kiel la angla vorto *tomb*.

La difino de tombo en la Reta Vortaro estas:

> Fosaĵo en tero aŭ ŝtona monumento, kien oni metas mortinton.

Ŝajne tio povas esti nur la malgranda fosaĵo kiu estas sufiĉe granda nur por la kadavro. Ĝi pli similas al la angla vorto *grave*. Tiuokaze la homoj ja estis starantaj ekster la tombo kaj metis la kadavrojn en la tombon, kaj la akuzativo havas sencon.

Answer (score 3):

> La hundo kuras en nia **domo**. - The dog runs **in** our house. The
>   dog is in the house and runs around there.
>
> La hundo kuras en nian **domon**. - The dog runs **into** our house.
>   The dog is outside of the house but now runs into the house.

http://lernu.net/en/gramatiko/akuzativo